# External Style is not detected by javascript (if conditon used)

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I am relative new to web development so while developing a project site responsive design I ran into a problem that when ever hamburger menu is pressed even though lines for expending exists in external css file but it is not detected but new inine styles are created by javascript and then it works as expected.
HTML:

```
<nav class="mobileNav" id="mobileMenu">
    <a class="mol-6" onclick="show();" href="index.html">
        <figure>
            <img class="icon" src="images/nav/home.png" alt="">
            <figcaption>Home</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
    <a class="mol-6" onclick="show();" href="astronomy.html">
        <figure>
            <img class="icon" src="images/nav/astro.png" alt="">
            <figcaption>Astronomy</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
    <a class="mol-6" onclick="show();" href="telescope.html">
        <figure>
            <img class="icon" src="images/nav/tele.png" alt="">
            <figcaption>Telescopes</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
    <a class="mol-6" onclick="show();" href="about.html">
        <figure>
            <img class="icon" src="images/nav/about.png" alt="">
            <figcaption>About</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#mobileMenu {
 font-family: light, sans-serif;
 max-height: 0px;
 z-index: 99;
 transform: translateY(-100%);
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0px;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function show() {
if (document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.maxHeight == "0px") {
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.maxHeight = "100%";
        document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.position = "fixed";
        document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.padding = "1%";
    }, 1)
    document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.transform = "translateY(0px)";
} else {
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.maxHeight = "0px";
        document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.padding = "0px";
        document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.position = "relative";
    }, 500)
    document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.transform = "translateY(-100%)";
}}
```

Working Example:
[Astromuneeb (Require Portrait Orientation)](http://astromuneeb.gear.host)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better approaches of what you are trying to accomplish. For instance, you could use css classes for styling and use javascript only for switching classes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will use this to update the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Eugene, but `.mobileNav` class seems to be overriding your portrait media query.

[image]

I added important to your `.mobileNav` portrait media query but even that won't override it, guess its something to do with hierarchy. It's weird you get `display:none;` as an inline style on your nav when opening and closing currently, that will not help.

Definitely just set a `.open` class as Eugene suggested. And use css transforms to do the animation. And just simply add/remove class on the nav.

And when using media queries in css for mobile etc prob best to use screen size etc, and start mobile first...

```
.mobileNav { display: block; }

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .mobileNav { display: none; }

}
```

Comment: The javascript is used for detecting the current state of menu was its max height not the display so I don't think it affects it.

Comment: Cool man glad your sorted it :-) maybe I looked at it when you were editing it or something because there was an inline style `display:none` on the `#mobileMenu` element when I clicked open/close.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it really helped me to create code better organized and that code was wrongly placed so thanks for pointing it out ...